# How to make slidesToScroll on arrow click 1, and on swipe 3 in slick slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swipe, slick.js

I have slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 3. But on click arrow I want to slide only 1 slide.
Please, help

Answer (score 1):

You can use "slickSetOption"

```
$('.slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', 1, true);
```

Comment: hm.. nothing changed...
this slider appears on mob here in schedule http://teslakarting.com/training/schedule/
There are object of settings in console. 
slidesToScroll 3, slidesToShow 3 is for screens < 586, on click I set slidesToScroll - 1 and call slickNext http://prntscr.com/fb4dxz